# 301 Redirects in JSP

Tags: jsp, redirect

I am using 301 redirect to redirect my old website pages to the new site.
The code for it as follows:

```
<%
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader( "Location", "http://my_new_website/page.html" );
response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
%>
```

So, whenever user reaches the old page, it will be automatically redirected to the new site page: http://my_new_website/page.html

Now I need a option like, during redirect from the old page to the new website, it must **display an message** something like "The website is moved" for a while and then automatically redirected the new website.

What should I do for this?
Can anyone suggest a way for it?

Comment: Why are you sending `Connection: close`? Connection management is a matter between the HTTP server and the browser's HTTP stack, and not something you should be worrying about on the content level.

Comment: FYI, your JSP hangs with Safari because it sends a `Content-Length: 1` in the headers and Safari waits for the body. You should add `response.setContentLength(0)` as well to make your JSP work in most browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could immediately redirect your user to the new site and check the `referrer` -  if it is the old site, you  could then present your user a message like "You have been redirected here because...".

Answer (score -1):

You want something like [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), I think.